# zend framework 2 models with doctrine 2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to understand Zend Framework 2.
For that, I started with Ron Allen's tutorial http://akrabat.com/getting-started-with-zend-framework-2/
then, I integrate doctrine 2, using the tutorial http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/
ok, before that I decide to make it more complex.

I change the database to the following:

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `album`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `album` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `artist` (`artist_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `artist`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

My application have this structure:

```
module
    Album
        src
            Album
                Controller
                    AlbumController.php
                Entity
                    Album.php
    Artist
        src
            Artist
                Controller
                    ArtistController.php
                Entity
                    Artist.php
```

My new Entities are like that:

```
class Album {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="album")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $artist;

    ...
}
class Artist {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Album", mappedBy="artist")
     */
    protected $album;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->album = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...
}
```

But It doesn't work!
I got this mensage:

```
"The target-entity Album\Entity\Artist cannot be found in 'Album\Entity\Album#artist'."
```

So my question is: What is wrong? My Entities are in the wrong place? or my module organization are not ok?
How can I make one entity be visible for more than one module?

**UPDATE:**

I change my entities to:

```
class Album {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Artist\Entity\Artist", inversedBy="album")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $artist;

    ...
}
class Artist {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Album\Entity\Album", mappedBy="artist")
     */
    protected $album;

    ...
}
```

But I got the same error:

```
"The target-entity Artist\Entity\Artist cannot be found in 'Album\Entity\Album#artist'."
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the structure of my application to:

```
module
    Album
        src
            Album
                Controller
                    AlbumController.php
                    ArtistController.php
                Entity
                    Album.php
                    Artist.php
```

so my entities are in the same namespace and now my program it's working! =)

But I still have the question: how can I make one entity to be visible to more than one mudule in ZF2?

Comment: Glad to see you got it working.  Doctrine 2 really does like entities to be in the same directory.  Symfony 2 has some wrapper code to allow multiple directories but I never really looked through the details.  You might be on your own at least until ZF2 is actually released and more people start using it.

Comment: yeah, I guess it's only a ZF2 question... but nobody have a answer for my questions... see, if you have a `album module` (with only selectOne and selectAll) and a `admin module` (with selectOne, selectAll, insert, update and delete), how you organize your entities? thats my question... but thank you very much for your help @Cerad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer! =D

I got to wait 8 hours to answer my own question, so here we go.

As I said, I reproducing the tutorial http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/

They teach how to configure the module to work with Doctrine 2.
In the file module/Album/config/module.config.php they insert the following code:

```
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            // ...
            'orm_driver_chain' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'drivers' => array(
                        'Album' => array(
                            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                            'namespace' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity',
                            'paths' => array(
                                __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

According to the tutorial:

> "This tells Doctrine that the Album module’s entities use the namespace
>   Album\Entity, and that the classes in that namespace are stored in
>   $PROJECT_DIR/module/Album/src/Album/Entity."

so, there is the problem!
Doctrine was configure to use only Album\Entity!
so I changed the code to the following (with bad programming... sorry):

```
//...
'drivers' => array(
    'Album' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'namespace' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity',
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'
        ),
    ),
    'Artist' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'namespace' => '\Artist\Entity',
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../../Artist/src/Artist/Entity'
        ),
    ),
//...
```

As you can see I configure an 'Artist' driver...

Now my application work properly! =)

I'm still looking for the right way to configure the doctrine in my application but at least I got the answer!

Thanks for everybody! :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your updated question:

Your Entities and all other code used in one module is "visible" within each other module, just instantiate it via

```
$artist = new \Album\Entity\Artist();
```

or whatever you may need.
Just make sure to have all your modules registered in your application configuration.

Comment: Uhm, that's nice! But why my doctrine doesn't work? It keeps showing that error msg...

Comment: The last lines of your questions suggest that there is no error. Would you please share the error?

Answer (score 0):

By default Doctrine 2 will look in the same namespace as the current entity for your related entities.  Something like:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Artist\Entity\Artist", inversedBy="album")
```

Will be needed.  Disclaimer:  I have not used ZF2.  I'm assuming your class loader paths are all setup.

Comment: uhm, nice. I'll try that. but its correct keep my models this way? or I supposed to put then all in the same namespace? I mean, I should have a directory 'models' if all my entities in there?

Comment: That is really up to you.  Symfony 2 is a bit more mature as far as namespaces and such.  You might browse through the documentation and see how they organize things.  But Doctrine really doesn't care.  Just needs to know where to look for the entity.

Comment: Update your question with your new entity code and error message.  If the error message really is the same then you forgot to update something.